# Shorten any number to 3 digits human readable number in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are a lot of nice 'human' helpers in Rails but in my situation I have to shorten numbers to 3 digits with dot separator and one-letter units (thousand - 'k', million - 'm', etc).

```
number_to_human(number, strip_insignificant_zeros: true, precision: 2).gsub(/ /,'')
```

this helper does great work except I need 25454 to become 25.5k but not 25.45k as it makes it.

In general, I need to set 'precision' option to 1 or 2 based on how many digits are before the dot.

I could wrap number_to_human by my own helper and calculate precision by my own, but I am wondering if there is another way, maybe some Ruby magics or something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, there is a function for *that* as well? :)

Comment: <sarcasm>? 
Rails' helpers work well with translations and default settings. That's why I would not like to write my own methods for such functionality if there is a 'Rails-way' to do that.

Comment: No, it's just that I had to write my own stuff for this, because I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Yeah. There are a lot of useful helpers for numbers manipulation in Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human) say the meaning of `precision` is controlled by the setting of `significant`.  By default it's the number of significant digits.  If you set `significant: false, precision: 1` you get the desired effect of saying you want only one digit following the decimal point.

Comment: Great! It works as expected with **precision** set to 3 and **significant** set to _true_